# CSS : How to do dynamic margin to crop a video based on the format of the site?

Tags: html, css

I got a video (16:9) that I want to crop dynamicly (possibly with negative margin) to fit the whole screen.
For a maximised window on PC I did

```
#homevid{
margin-top: -7%;
margin-bottom: -7%;}
```

But what should I do to also crop the sides when viewed on mobile and switch between both/adapt to weird aspect ratio ?

Comment: does this help: https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured an answer, I can just use

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

The css style you write inside this is only executed when the client screen is thinner than 540px:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
   //Your code 
}
```

The css style you write inside this is only executed when the client screen is wide than 540px:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 540px) {
   //Your css
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but still helpfull, thank you !